# SignalR Hub Server Doesn't Recover after Disconnect Errors

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a ASP.NET project using a hub from the SignalR package.  The websocket frequently will lose connection.

This leads to the javascript error:  "Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'"

The server then becomes unable to serve any page that involves SignalR, even to totally different clients.  After a while, the server recovers (presumably once the connection times out.) The server can still serve pages that don't have SignalR in them.

Clientside, it builds the connection like this:

```
var conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/someHub").build();
conn.start();
```

So how can I force the server to forget whatever dead connections are breaking it?

First I tried adding a reconnect feature to the client side.  This works fine client side, but the server still is dead from the failed connection.

Next attempt was to wrap every Hub method in try catches.  The catch logged the error in a db, and called Dispose() on the Hub.

```
public async SendMessage(string messageText){
try{
 await Clients.Group("SomeGroupName").SendAsync("SomeCommand",messageText);

}catch(Exception e){
 database.Log(e.ToString());
this.Dispose();
}
}
```

Next I tried overriding the OnDisconnectedAsync method:

```
public async override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception){
 try{
if(exception != null){
 database.Log(exception.ToString());
 this.Dispose();
}

}catch(Exception e){
 database.Log(e.ToString());
}
}
```

None of these ever logged any error. I tried variations using this.Context.Abort() with the same results. I conclude the server is going bad without entering any of my functions. I haven't been able to reproduce the error in a local development environment, which limits the debugging ability.

So how to stop SignalR from bringing down the whole server after one bad disconnect?  Reconnecting on the client side doesn't help.  Having the server unavailable for all users for a minute or two while it forgets about the bad connection is unacceptable.